# How do you export layer information into a shapefile?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, layers

Using ArcMap 10.8.1, trying to use information from the Web Soil Survey (using the viewer add-on, of course). I'm going to do the rest of my workflow in R/RStudio, I just need the data to be exported into a shapefile that I can use. I'm looking at Oregon, and a couple of layers--let's focus on available water supply for now.

[image: Obviously, I can get the data in okay lol]

I can load in the data, like you see here. Of note, maybe: when it saves and I reload it, it doesn't seem to want to display the layers of interest.

[image]

Not sure why that is. In addition, when I have tried to highlight layers to export to shapefile, I've ended up with a file that only seems to have the basic area information, not the layers I wanted. For instance, the dimensions I ended up with using R's `sf::st_read` were

`[1] "AREASYMBOL" "SPATIALVER" "MUSYM"      "MUKEY"      "geometry"`

so not exactly helpful there.

I know I don't know how to use ArcMap. But it seems like it should be a simple process to export a map like this as a shapefile?

Comment: Is your soils data a web service? It's possible that the data provider has disabled exporting, or partial exports to stop people such as yourself making uncontrolled copies.

Comment: In general, maps *aren't* exported as shapefile, because shapefile only stores one geometry and some attributes per row, and the attribute schema and geometry type have to be the same for every row. Maps are constructed of several to several dozen layers, often of different geometry classes, plus rasters, some of which could be assembled from multiple sources as well.

Comment: The service is the web soil survey, which you download data from freely; it could be a question of access, but that strikes me as unlikely given the open distribution of the data in the first place.

Comment: The data here depend on particular soil survey areas to load the data with an mdb file (Access database). I'd also be fine to export the layers somehow to load them on top of the geometry into R--and I'll look into that. But when the data are necessarily tied to the same polygons, why can't I store information in those fields akin to shapefiles I've seen elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out: there's a directory under `C:\Users\<your name>\AppData\Local\USDA\Soil Data Viewer 6.2\temp` that contains (temporary) text files and shapefiles for the data in question as long as it's open in ArcMap. Not sure how to use it the "right" way, but I can replicate the data now in RStudio:

[image]

The Web Soil Survey may be useful, but it does seem a bit tough to figure out a workflow for.